# Openerp function fields

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Hey I'm new to openerp and I need help to create a function field called Total that calculates the sum of all the fields of the same object...
eg.

```
_name = 'hr.performanzze'
_columns = {
    'p':fields.selection(((1,'Outstanding'), (2,'Well Above Expectations'), (3,'As Expected'), (4,'Below Expectations'), (5,'VeryPoor'), 0,'N/A')),'title.'),
    'b':fields.selection(((1,'Outstanding'), (2,'Well Above Expectations'), (3,'As Expected'), (4,'Below Expectations'), (5,'Very Poor'), (0,'N/A')),'title'),
    'total' : fields.function(get_total, method=True, string='Total Mark'),
}
def get_total(self, cr, uid, field_name, arg, context):
    #want to calculate the sum of p and b
    return the answer
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @lesalami. Check out the documentation that QGerome linked to, and then make your question more specific if you still need help.

Answer (score 5):

```
def get_total(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
    res = []
    perfos = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
    for perfo in perfos:
        res[perfo.id] = perfo.p + perfo.b

    return res
```

Answer (score 2):

Start here : [Documentation of fields](http://doc.openerp.com/v5.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#fnct-parameter)

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_total(self, cr, uid, field_name, arg, context):
    for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        return obj.p + obj.b
```

One can directly use browse method and access list of data attached with that record.