# Add(Sum) two values in odoo

Tags: odoo

Suppose I have two field. Such as num1 and num2. I want to show the sum of these values in tree view. How to apply this in odoo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this by `onchange` method, here is a demo of onchange method using **new api of odoo**.

```
class DemoModel(models.Model):

    _name = 'demo.model'

    field_x = fields.Integer('Column X')
    field_y = fields.Integer('Column Y')
    field_sum = fields.Integer('Column Sum')

    @api.onchange('field_x', 'field_y')
    def onchange_field(self):
        if self.field_x or self.field_y:
            self.field_sum = self.field_x + self.field_y
```

you don't need to change anything in view part(xml).

Comment: bro, getting NameError: name 'api' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

Create a 3rd field called `result`, that sums the `num1` and `num2` using a onchange or functional field with defaults. You can hide it in form view and show it in tree view.

Since functional fields are computed everytime a view is loaded, don't go for it, if you're going to use it in tree view because it will drastically slow the view loading as the records and computation gets complex. You can use `store=true` to force the value to be stored in database also.

If it is written in qweb, the above case will be handed differently.

Update:

For more info about [onchange...](http://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/06_misc_on_change_tips.html)

Code for sum using onchange:
In python file:

```
class sample_test(osv.osv):
    _name = "sample.test"

    _columns = {
                'num1': fields.integer('Num1'),
                'num2': fields.integer('Num2'),
                'result': fields.integer('Result'),
                }

    def onchange_result(self, cr, uid, ids, num1, num2, context=None):
        res = {}
        if num1 and numb2:
            res['result'] = numb1 + numb2
        return {'value': res}
```

In xml file:

```
<field name="num1" on_change="onchange_result(num1, num2)" />
<field name="num2" on_change="onchange_result(num1, num2)" />
<field name="result" />
```

For functional field refer:

Syntax: https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#functional-fields

Description: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/7.0/view/head:/openerp/osv/fields.py#L843

Simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11981080/3374651

Comment: store=True does not store the value. It reset to 0.0

Comment: in what field you used store=true, its a functional field property.

Comment: Sorry bro. Worked. Thanks. If I set readonly true then the prblm. I want it not editable

Comment: You need it only in treeview, so you don't need to provide it in form view. Or else go for functional field with store=true.

Comment: Try to upvote, accept answer if it worked for you, and downvote if it doesn't.

Comment: I have low reputation to upvote. Sorry bro to vote. Can u please give an example code with field.function

Comment: Bro, as followed your link I have got a problem. Here is my another ques. Would be greatful pls answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/29881228/4718335

Answer (score 0):

you  are write wrong variables numb1 numb2 in condition

class calc(osv.osv):
    _name = "calc"

```
_columns = {
            'num1': fields.integer('Num1'),
            'num2': fields.integer('Num2'),
            'result': fields.integer('Result'),
            }

def onchange_result(self, cr, uid, ids, num1, num2, context=None):
    res = {}
    if num1 and num2:
        res['result'] = num1 + num2
    return {'value': res}
```

calc()